# How can I combine the part-duplicate data in a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I'm processing my data from MIMIC dataset. Some of my data are like that:
(the data type is pandas.dataframe)

```
time  A  B  C D
01:00 2 NaN 3 4
02:00 2 NaN 3 4
03:00 2 NaN 3 4
01:00 NaN 4 3 4
```

`NaN` means missing data.

Obviously line 1 and line 4(they are token in same time) should be combined.
But how can I do that?

The output I need is like:

```
time  A  B  C D
01:00 2  4  3 4
02:00 2 NaN 3 4
03:00 2 NaN 3 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sum the other rows , here is the code :

```
df.groupby(['time']).sum()
```

or

```
df.groupby(['time']).max()
```

for more : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: yep I know the sum method. But here I need to keep the other data in a row (they are same except NaN), not to sum them.

Comment: can you edit the question and show me the output you need ?

Comment: ok I just added the output I need !

Comment: ok. just use max()